# Larry, Moe, Curly Mutual Exclusion

Tags: c, pthreads, semaphore, mutual-exclusion

Problem Statement:

> "Larry, Moe, and Curly are planting seeds. Larry digs the holes. Moe
>   then places a seed in each hole. Curly then fills the hole up. There
>   are several synchronization constraints:
>
> - Moe cannot plant a seed unless at least one empty hole exists, but Moe does not care how far Larry gets ahead of Moe.
> - Curly cannot fill a hole unless at least one hole exists in which Moe has planted a seed, but the hole has not yet been filled. Curly
>     does not care how far Moe gets ahead of Curly.
> - Curly does care that Larry does not get more than MAX holes ahead of Curly. Thus, if there are MAX unfilled holes, Larry has to wait.
> - There is only one shovel with which both Larry and Curly need to dig and fill the holes, respectively.
>
> Design, implement and test a
>   solution for this IPC problem, which represent Larry, Curly, and Moe.
>   Use semaphores as the synchronization mechanism."

I've typed up a program from some pseudocode that I was given, but I'm getting the error:

```
project2part3.c:13:13: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion] 
 #define MAX 5
             ^
project2part3.c:22:18: note: in expansion of macro 'MAX'
 sem_t unfilled = MAX;
                   ^
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

#define MAX 5

void *larry();
void *moe();
void *curly();

pthread_mutex_t shovel = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
sem_t empty;
sem_t seeded;
sem_t unfilled;

int main(){
    pthread_t ltid;
    pthread_t mtid;
    pthread_t ctid;
    //initializing the semaphores
    sem_init(&empty, 0, 0);
    sem_init(&seeded, 0, 0);
    sem_init(&unfilled, 0, 0);

    pthread_create(&ltid, NULL, larry, NULL);  //create the larry thread
    pthread_create(&mtid, NULL, moe, NULL);  //create the moe thread
    pthread_create(&ctid, NULL, curly, NULL);  //create the curly thread

    pthread_join(ltid,NULL);
    pthread_join(mtid,NULL);
    pthread_join(ctid,NULL);
}

void *larry(){
    while(1){
        sem_wait(unfilled);
        sem_wait(shovel);
        //Dig the hole
        printf("Digging");
        sem_post(shovel);
        sem_post(empty);
    }
}

void *moe(){
    while(1){
        sem_wait(empty);
        //Seed the hole
        printf("Seeding");
        sem_post(seeded);
    }
}

void *curly(){
    while(1){
        sem_wait(seeded);
        sem_wait(shovel);
        //Fill the hole
        printf("Filling");
        sem_post(shovel);
        sem_post(unfilled);
    }
}
```

Comment: Which line is the error pointing to? Show the full error statement

Comment: Functions are declared as `void*`, but are not returning any values. Fishy. Also `main` is not returning anything. Also functions not taking parameters should be declared as `(void)`. I would say you should get much more warnings.

Comment: `sem_t unfilled = MAX;` That's not how you initialize a semaphore...

Comment: It's like the compiler is telling you the exact location and the exact error and you are asking "what's wrong"?

Comment: @EugeneSh., a `main` with no explicit return implicitly returns 0. It's a wonderful feature that saves me about 10 key strokes every time I write a `main`.

Comment: @eran I *think* that is not true. The value returned without an explicit `return` statement is undefined. **Update:** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3727051/why-does-a-main-function-without-a-return-statement-return-value-12

Comment: @EugeneSh. It really returns 0 as per the standard, but it's **not** implicitly returning `EXIT_SUCCESS`, which - of different from 0 - could cause issues.

Comment: @DanielJour Well, that's tricky point. I wouldn't save 10 keystrokes on it.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I'm not that lazy, too. But some ... well, it's a nice topic for a flame war :D

Comment: the posted code when fed to the compiler causes the compiler to output 20 error and warning statements.  (using `gcc -c -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu99 filename.c -o filename.o -I. -I/usr/include` )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sem_t shovel = 1; // Note: Is a lock in the updated question code
sem_t empty = 0;
sem_t seeded = 0;
sem_t unfilled = MAX;
```

That's **not** how you initialise semaphores. They're complex things, not just counters that can be assigned to. That's the reason there's the function `sem_init`, which you're using, but not correctly. [Read up on it in a reference of your choice](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sem_init).

IIRC `sem_t` is a typedef similar to

```
typedef struct whatever * sem_t;
```

Thus each of the above lines initialises a pointer from an integer.

Furthermore, your functions should return what you declare them to return. This is especially true for the functions used for the threads: They (need to) declare that they return a void pointer, so (if you don't have anything meaningful to return) just use

```
return NULL;
```

at the end of reach of these.

Moreover:

```
pthread_create(&btid, NULL, larry, NULL);  //create the larry thread
pthread_create(&btid, NULL, moe, NULL);  //create the moe thread
pthread_create(&btid, NULL, curly, NULL);  //create the curly thread
```

You want these calls to different `thread_t`s, not all to the same (`btid`).

Comment: note: the posted code is declaring `shovel` as a pthread_mutex, NOT as a semaphore,  so every reference to shovel should use the `pthread_mutex_lock()` or `pthread_mutex_unlock()` functions not `semwait()` and not `sempost()`

Comment: @user3629249 Indeed, I added a note. I'm planning on keeping it in as it resembles the original question's code and lines up better with the rest of the questions code.